# Initial View Controller on top level of hierarchy loses NavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, hierarchy

I have a hierarchy of 3 TableViewControllers embeded in Navigation Controller and I need to launch on the most detailed level on the top of the hierarchy. If I change 'Is Initial View Controller' in storyboard to the last detailed TableViewController, my app launches with the selected TVC, but with no NavigationBar. How can I launch on the desired level of hierarchy and keep the Navigation Controller managing the stack of views?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling the storyboard that your third view controller is the root view controller--it has no navigation bar.  If you want the navigation controller present as the root view controller then you need to make it the initial view controller, then change the navigation's root to your third view controller.

eg:

```
initial-->[navigation controller]-->[third VC]   [first VC]-->[second VC] (keep these around if you want... just disconnect them from the navigation controller)
```

Comment: I did the change in storyboard, got the third VC on launch with navigation bar, but there is no way to reach the other level of hierarchy, even if I connect the first and second VC to the third one. I guess I would then have to segue manually (in code) from third to second etc. if needed and pass the context along?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear one what you want.  Are you expecting that VC's 1, 2 and 3 are already on the navigation stack when the app launches?  Or are you wanting 3 at the root of the navigation stack and then some way to get from 3 to 1 (and then 2)?

Comment: As mentioned below, I want to start the view on the Day level (3rd level) and have the possibility to go back to Month and Year level with leftBarButtonItem (back button) which is the 2nd and 1st level. I will do the segues in code if you think it is possible to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to go back to your original storyboard and have the navigation controller be the initial view.  Then when the navigation controller's viewDidLoad is called you'll have to do two manual segues to get the other two VC's pushed.  It's kind of a weird use-case though, so you might want to reconsider if it's the best design.

Comment: It looks like an elegant solution to the problem. Do you mean I should call the segue from viewDidLoad of the individual VCs, or subclass Navigation Controller and call it 2 times from its viewDidLoad? When I call the segue from individual VCs, the thing actually works, but when I go to the root in hierarchy and down again, the second VCs viewDidLoad is called again and I get log in console 'nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar' and my views then break apart from the navigation bar. When I tried to subclass Navigation Contr., it's viewDidLoad didn't recognize my segues.

Comment: For your case you probably want the viewDidLoad for your navigation controller.  This will get called when the navigation controller is initially created (you'll need to subclass UINavigationController and set the navigation controller's class in the storyboard to use your subclass).  If you try to push a segue in the individual VC's viewDidLoad then every time one of your VC's instances is created it will also push the next VC, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: OK. I just wonder why my subclassed Navigation Controller does not recognize the segues? In it's viewDidLoad: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YearToMonth" sender:self]; leads to.. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<NavigationController: 0xa07c710>) has no segue with identifier 'YearToMonth'

Comment: Ah, each VC only knows about its own segues.  The navigation controller only knows what its root VC is.  So you probably need to call performSegueWithIdentifier on the navigation controller's root VC.

Comment: So I call performSegueWithIdentifier on the Year VC, then the same on the month VC and on the way back from the top level the VCs and navbar breaks apart with the nested animations complain. I guess each VC is new instance when using storyboard segues and that's why the viewDidLoad is called again?

Comment: So on the end I resolved the nested animations issue like this: I call performSegueWithIdentifier from individual VCs in their viewDidLoad, but maintain global variable to make sure the segue in code is performed only on launch. This way I avoid double segue when new instance of VC is loaded from storyboard. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to select the ViewController that you want as initial and embed it into a NavigationController, and then add all of the other views after that using push segues.

But why do that? Why not just have the first viewcontroller display the data that you will have in the third view controller? you will end up with the same results.

You should also check out [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1).

Comment: The reason is to preserve the context of the hierarchy. Think of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd level like year, month and day. I want to start the view in day and have the possibility to go back one level to the proper month.

Comment: @MartinKoles from reading the comments in the answer below, what you could do is just create a custom button on your first screen (which you can name "back" if you like) which will segue you to the next view. create the month and year views after the day view (in that order) and use push segues to move across.